# Python3 virtualenv: ImportError: no module named 'ConfigParser'

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

I'm working on OSX and I'm trying to create a virtualenv with Python3, but I'm getting an error:

```
$ virtualenv --python python3 env
Running virtualenv with interpreter /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 37, in <module>
    import ConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 39, in <module>
    import configparser as ConfigParser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/configparser.py", line 397
    _KEYCRE = re.compile(ur"%\(([^)]+)\)s")
```

It looks like it's looking for `ConfigParser`, which has been renamed `configparser`. Is that right? What can I do?

I've tried to update virtualenv with `pip install -U virtualenvwrapper` but it hasn't helped.

Comment: Also same problem if I do: `virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3 .venv`

Comment: In Python 3, why not use [`pyvenv`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30233408/1157100) instead?

Comment: This is still an issue, but only after I updated to El Capitan. I don't know if OP has similar circumstances, but I'm surprised that this didn't create an error sooner. And even after setting up `pyenv`, I am getting this error when i try to make a `virtualenv` with `python3`. Uninstalling and reinstalling(with both `pip` and `pip3`) `virtualenvwrapper` and `virtualenv` also did not solve the issue.

Comment: Also — to clarify my final traceback line is instead ```ImportError: This package should not be accessible on Python 3. Either you are trying to run from the python-future src folder or your installation of python-future is corrupted.``` I don't know if that may help you, but a similar uninstall and reinstall of `future` via pip and pip3 did nothing to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, and I'm not certain if this will solve you problem, but for me it was due to a new version of python-future which jumped the queue in my path (ahead of the core python `configparser`) and then ran into issues.

What solved the problem for me was just removing the `configparser.py` file from that directory, since that wasn't the `configparser` that `virtualenv` is looking for.

To be fair, I think this issue was introduced in a more recent version of future (which is why I had a different error from you) but I imagine that given the path that your traceback is coming from, the issue still stems from it running into a `configparser` module that `virtualenv` doesn't expect to be there.

I'm [filing an issue](https://github.com/PythonCharmers/python-future/issues/181) with the `python-future` folks, but other than that, I don't really know how to solve this issue other than to eliminate the version of `configparser` from its position on the path. Unfortunately, that also messes with future's ability to allow equivalence between import statements in python2 and python3.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

problem solved after I upgrade to latest version of virtualenv 15.1.

```
pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

Comment: Didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I think virtualenv should be installed for both python2&3, so I fixed this error by installing virtualenv for python3.

```
sudo python3 -m pip install virtualenv
```

Comment: It does not need to be installed as both. When calling virtualenv, only one of the two will be used. However, it does need to be up to date.